# Make Html Label show on right side of Div element

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a DIV element:

```
<div style="background-color:red">This is a test
    <label>ID:</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"><asp:Textbox>
</div>
```

I need to show "This is a test" on left side but the Label and Textbox  on the right side of the side.

I tried

```
margin:right 0px;
```

but this did not help.

Also tried Float:right but this created strange results.

Comment: There is no value `right` for margin. Are you trying `position: absolute; right: 0` ? Can you create a demo of the issue?

Comment: That is close to what I need. Is these a way to select the top position in this div? If I select  top:10px; it seems it compare it to the top of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a div to wrap the label and input, and use `float`:

```css
.input-group {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red">This is a test
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>ID:</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I mentioned I need "This is a test" on the left side

Comment: Updated as per the clarifiying comment.

Comment: Still I see the "This is a test" on the right side.

Comment: @S Nash - Are you sure?  Click the "Run code snippet" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `float:right;` in your style:

```
<div style="background-color:red">This is a test
    <div style="float:right">
        <label>ID:</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"><asp:Textbox>
    </div>
</div>
```